# How does one ask for super-plain vanilla standard input?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I find when I'm typing a line like this to a clisp program's standard input ...

```
((74 25 80))
```

... the cursor seems to dance, and it doesn't matter whether I'm doing

```
(read)
```

or

```
(read-from-string (read-line))
```

That is, when I type each right parenthesis, the cursor briefly hovers over the matching left parenthesis.  If I type ahead, sometimes the whole line typed up to that point is re-echoed back to me.

This would be fine, I guess, but I'm doing this over a pty, and I want the input from that pty (what shows up on the clisp program's standard output and error output) to be "clean".  No dancing cursor, no re-echoing of the line.

I suppose I could use named pipes for the input and output, but I want to handle this through the pty.

How do I make standard input be purely vanilla?  No dancing cursor?  No re-echoing of typeahead?  Can I just modify a configuration file somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like GNU Readline is being used.  There's a -disable-readline command line flag for clisp [according to this page](http://clisp.org/impnotes/clisp.html).  Failing that, I think you're going to have to use a pipe to either convince readline that it isn't reading from a terminal or that it isn't outputting to a terminal.

Comment: Your diagnosis seems correct.  My clisp isn't new enough to have the '-disable-readline' option, but wrapping a shell script around the program 'cat | myprogram | cat' does the trick!  Thank you!